# Find the value of a convergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So the series $$\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi^{3}}{8 \cdot 3!} + \frac{\pi^{5}}{32 \cdot 5!} - \cdot\cdot\cdot$$
is convergent, I need to find the value where it converges to

So far I have determined the pattern should be an alternating series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \, \frac{\pi^{2n-1}}{2^{2n-1} \cdot (2n-1)!}$$

But I need some help finding the value of convergence

Comment: Look up the Taylor expansion of the $sin$ function , the answer should be 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{n-1}=i^{2n-2}$

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{i\pi}2\right)^{2n-1}}{i(2n-1)!}=\dfrac{e^{\dfrac{i\pi}2}-e^{\dfrac{-i\pi}2}}{2i}=\sin\dfrac{\pi}2$$

using $\displaystyle e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}{r!}$

and [Simple Proof of the Euler Identity $\exp{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839410/simple-proof-of-the-euler-identity-expi-theta-cos-thetai-sin-theta)

Comment: Hi there, my bad. It's actually that $\{ a_{n} \}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$