# What is the relation to $\sinh{x},\cosh{x}$ and $\sin{x},\cos{x}$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I've learned what $\sinh{x},\cosh{x}$ (the hyperbolic trig functions) are defined as formula, but how is it related to $\sin{x},\cos{x}?$
The only thing I've noticed is that $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1.$

Comment: See, for instance, ["What's the intuition behind the identities $\cos(z)=\cosh(iz)$ and $\sin(z)=-i\sinh(iz)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736068/whats-the-intuition-behind-the-identities-cosz-coshiz-and-sinz-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They’re related by Euler’s formula. Since $e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x$ we have $e^{-ix}=\cos x-i \sin x$. This reveals,

$$\cosh (ix)=\cos x$$

$$\sinh (ix)=i \sin x$$