# Proof for hyperbolic trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I've been studying hyperbolic functions and was wondering where the following two identities were derived from:

$$\sinh(x) = \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$$

$$\cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$$

I understand how to use these to prove other identities and I understand how to use Euler's formula to find the identities for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ but I am unable to find any proof for these two. Perhaps I am just unsure what to search for, so if there is a proof somewhere already I would love some directions or links.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you *define* $\sinh$ and $\cosh$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the intuition behind the identities $\cos(z)= \cosh(iz)$ and $\sin(z)=-i\sinh(iz)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736068/whats-the-intuition-behind-the-identities-cosz-coshiz-and-sinz-i)

Comment: The proposed "duplicate" question asked for intuition, not proof. My interpretation of _this_ question is it is asking for proof. There is some ambiguity in the question because it does not give a sufficient hint about what facts we might derive the formulas from, but nevertheless it is asking for a derviation.

Comment: If you don't give a definition of these functions, no proof of anything can be given and the question should be closed.

Comment: see how hyperbolic function of an imaginary angle $ \cosh ix = \cos x$ is derived as a real quantity.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757241/409), which develops the functions geometrically and derives the exponential forms with the help of an elementary integral.

Answer (score 5):

You can't answer this until you have defined the hyperbolic functions !

One way is via the complex numbers,

$$i\sinh x:=\sin ix,
\\\cosh x:=\cos ix,$$ giving

$$\sin ix=\frac{e^{i^2x}-e^{-i^2x}}{2i},
\\\cos ix=\frac{e^{i^2x}+e^{-i^2x}}2,$$
or
$$\sin ix=\frac{e^{-x}-e^{x}}{2i},
\\\cos ix=\frac{e^{-x}+e^x}2.$$

---

The qualifier *hyperbolic* comes from the relation

$$\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$$ or $$u^2-v^2=1,$$ i.e. an equilateral hyperbola. (Compare to $u^2+v^2=1$.)

Answer (score 4):

The hyperbolic functions are defined as the even and odd parts of $\exp x$ so $\exp\pm x=\cosh x\pm\sinh x$, in analogy with $\exp\pm ix=\cos x\pm i\sin x$. Rearranging gives the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to define $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ is to use the Taylor series expansions  for $e^x$ and and $e^{-x}$, that is $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {x^n}{n!}$$ $$e^{-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {(-1)^nx^n}{n!}$$

We add the first two series to get $$e^x + e^{-x} = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {x^{2n}}{2n!}$$ or $$\dfrac {e^x + e^{-x}}{2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {x^{2n}}{2n!}$$  As the sum of the right side is similar to $\cos (x)$, we can define $\cosh(x)$ as $$\cosh (x) \Leftrightarrow \dfrac {e^x + e^{-x}}{2}.$$

Now, subtracting the two series yields $$e^x - e^{-x} = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ or $$\dfrac {e^x - e^{-x}}{2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac {(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ As the sum of the right side is similar to the series for $\sin(x)$, we can define $\sinh(x)$ as $$\sinh (x) \Leftrightarrow \dfrac {e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$$.

Comment: "As the right side is the series for $\cos(x)$" -- Did you mean $\cosh(x)$?

Comment: Yes, sir...I was thinking one thing and doing another.  I've corrected the post.

Comment: In what way does this address the question ?

Comment: The original poster was asking how the hyperbolic functions were derived. In addition to the other ways other posters have illustrated, we can also derive $\cosh x$ and $\sinh x$ through the Taylor series of $e^x$ and $e^{−x}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think nobody has quite said that the **most common** definition of $\sinh,\cosh$ are in fact by the expressions you just wrote down. From these and the properties of $\exp$ we can derive all their other properties. Certainly the mathematicians who originally defined these did not know about complex numbers, much less envision the close relation between $\sinh,\cosh$ and $\sin,\cos$ via the complex exponential function. So if we define these four functions by the following for any complex $z$:
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

> $\cosh(z) = \lfrac12(\exp(z)+\exp(-z))$.
>
> $\sinh(z) = \lfrac12(\exp(z)-\exp(-z))$.
>
> $\cos(z) = \lfrac12(\exp(iz)+\exp(-iz))$.
>
> $\sin(z) = \lfrac1{2i}(\exp(iz)-\exp(-iz))$.

Then we get the following easy results:

> $\cosh(z) = \cos(iz)$.
>
> $\cos(z) = \cosh(iz)$.
>
> $\sinh(z) = -i\sin(iz)$.
>
> $\sin(z) = -i\sinh(iz)$.

And hence every trigonometric identity can be easily transformed into a hyperbolic identity and vice versa.

Once you prove that $\exp' = \exp$, you can recover all the basic properties of $\exp$ and hence $\cosh,\sinh,\cos,\sin$, including:

> $\cosh' = \sinh$.
>
> $\sinh' = \cosh$.
>
> $\cos' = -\sin$.
>
> $\sin' = \cos$.
>
> $\cos(x+y) = \cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$.
>
> $\sin(x+y) = \cos(x)\sin(y)+\sin(x)\cos(y)$.

If you further define $π$ as the first positive real root of $\cos$, which you can prove exists by some simple real analysis, you can also get the well-known:

> $\exp(iπ)+1=0$, and more generally that $2πi$ is the period of $\exp$.

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2360276/21820) for more details.

Comment: Here is an interesting related MAA article: [The Early Drama of the Hyperbolic Functions](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/321922717729.pdf.bannered.pdf).